# Searching for Unicode characters in Python

Tags: python, unicode, nltk

I'm working on a NLP project based on Python/NLTK with non-english unicode text. For that, I need to search unicode string inside a sentence.

There is a **.txt** file saved with some non-english unicode sentences. Using NLTK **PunktSentenceTokenizer** i broke them and saved in a python list.

```
sentences = PunktSentenceTokenizer().tokenize(text)
```

Now i can iterate through list and get each `sentence` separately.

---

What i need to do is go through that `sentence` and identify which word has the given unicode characters.

Example -

```
sentence = 'AASFG BBBSDC FEKGG SDFGF'
```

Assume above text is non-english unicode and i need to find words ending with `GF` then return whole word (may be index of that word).

```
search = 'SDFGF'
```

Similarly i need to find words starting with `BB` get the word of it.

```
search2 = 'BBBSDC'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just have to split up the sentence into words, loop over each one and check if it ends or starts with the required characters, e.g:

```
>>> sentence = ['AASFG', 'BBBSDC', 'FEKGG', 'SDFGF']
>>> [word for word in sentence.split() if word.endswith("GF")]
['SDFGF']
```

`sentence.split()` could probably be replaced with something like `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)`

**Update**, regarding comment:

> How can get word in-front of that and behind it

The `enumerate` function can be used to give each word a number, like this:

```
>>> print list(enumerate(sentence))
[(0, 'AASFG'), (1, 'BBBSDC'), (2, 'FEKGG'), (3, 'SDFGF')]
```

Then if you do the same loop, but preserve the index:

```
>>> results = [(idx, word) for (idx, word) in enumerate(sentence) if word.endswith("GG")]
>>> print results
[(2, 'FEKGG')]
```

..you can use the index to get the next or previous item:

```
>>> for r in results:
...     r_idx = r[0]
...     print "Prev", sentence[r_idx-1]
...     print "Next", sentence[r_idx+1]
...
Prev BBBSDC
Next SDFGF
```

You'd need to handle the case where the match the very first or last word (`if r_idx == 0`, `if r_idx ==  len(sentence)`)

Comment: Now I got another question. From above code i could able to find words ending or starting with given letters. How can get word in-front of that and behind it. For example, if i search for GG and got FEKGG and then i need to get BBBSDC as word in-front and SDFGF and word behind.