# Find word infront and behind of a Python list

Tags: python

This is related to following question - [Searching for Unicode characters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043041/searching-for-unicode-characters-in-python/18043155)

I have string like this -

```
sentence = 'AASFG BBBSDC FEKGG SDFGF'
```

I split it and get list of words like below -

```
sentence = ['AASFG', 'BBBSDC', 'FEKGG', 'SDFGF']
```

I search of part of a word using following code and get whole word -

```
[word for word in sentence.split() if word.endswith("GG")]
```

It returns `['FEKGG']`

Now i need to find out what is infront and behind of that word.

For example when i search for "GG" it returns `['FEKGG']`. Also it should able to get

```
behind = 'BBBSDC'
infront = 'SDFGF'
```

Comment: Can you please select a valid answer if one of us gave what you needed?

Comment: Please select a valid answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using this generator:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323910/866930)

If you have the following string (edited from original):

```
sentence = 'AASFG BBBSDC FEKGG SDFGF KETGG'

def neighborhood(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    prev = None
    item = iterator.next()  # throws StopIteration if empty.
    for next in iterator:
        yield (prev,item,next)
        prev = item
        item = next
    yield (prev,item,None)

matches = [word for word in sentence.split() if word.endswith("GG")]
results = []

for prev, item, next in neighborhood(sentence.split()):
    for match in matches:
        if match == item:
            results.append((prev, item, next))
```

This returns:

```
[('BBBSDC', 'FEKGG', 'SDFGF'), ('SDFGF', 'KETGG', None)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility:

```
words = sentence.split()
[pos] = [i for (i, word) in enumerate(words) if word.endswith("GG") ]
behind = words[pos - 1]
infront = words[pos + 1]
```

You might need to take care with edge-cases, such as `"…GG"` not appearing, appearing more than once, or being the first and/or last word. As it stands, any of these will raise an exception, which may well be the correct behaviour.

A completely different solution using regexes avoids splitting the string into an array in the first place:

```
match = re.search(r'\b(\w+)\s+(?:\w+GG)\s+(\w+)\b', sentence)
(behind, infront) = m.groups()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. The infront and behind elements will be `None` if the "GG" word is at the beginning or end of the sentence.

```
words = sentence.split()
[(infront, word, behind) for (infront, word, behind) in 
 zip([None] + words[:-1], words, words[1:] + [None])
 if word.endswith("GG")]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = 'AASFG BBBSDC FEKGG SDFGF AAABGG FOOO EEEGG'

def make_trigrams(l):
    l = [None] + l + [None]

    for i in range(len(l)-2):
        yield (l[i], l[i+1], l[i+2])


for result in [t for t in make_trigrams(sentence.split()) if t[1].endswith('GG')]:
    behind,match,infront = result

    print 'Behind:', behind
    print 'Match:', match
    print 'Infront:', infront, '\n'
```

Output:

```
Behind: BBBSDC
Match: FEKGG
Infront: SDFGF

Behind: SDFGF
Match: AAABGG
Infront: FOOO

Behind: FOOO
Match: EEEGG
Infront: None
```

Comment: This is what you were looking for, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

another itertools based option, may be more memory friendly on large datasets

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def sentence_targets(sentence, endstring):
   before, target, after = tee(sentence.split(), 3)
   # offset the iterators....
   target.next()
   after.next()
   after.next()
   for trigram in izip(before, target, after):
       if trigram[1].endswith(endstring): yield trigram
```

**EDIT**: fixed typo

Comment: AttributeError: 'itertools.tee' object has no attribute 'endswith'