# NLTK remove stop words from CSV

Tags: python, csv, unicode, nltk, stop-words

Though this is a common question, I couldn't find a solution for it that works for my case. I have data, which is comma separated like below.

```
['my scientific','data']['is comma-separated','frequency']
```

I'm trying to remove stop words using

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopword = stopwords.words('english')
mynewtext = [w for w in transposed if w not in stopword]
out_file.writerow(w)
```

But it gives me an error saying 'UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal'. I'm not sure where I'm committing a mistake. I want my output in a csv file to be like

```
scientific,data
comma-separated,frequency
```

Also, I'd want it to work for both the cases, upper and lower. casefield doesn't work in my Python version 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-,
```

in the header of your source code.

It tells Python that the source file you've saved is `utf-8`. The default for **Python 2** is ASCII (for **Python 3** it's `utf-8`). This just affects how the interpreter reads the characters in the file.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are comparing a `str object` to a `unicode object` in the above code.

I suggest you to take a look in the link [Python unicode equal comparison failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193305/python-unicode-equal-comparison-failed)

```
>>> s1 = u'Hello'
>>> s2 = unicode("Hello")
>>> type(s1), type(s2)
(<type 'unicode'>, <type 'unicode'>)
>>> s1==s2
True
>>> 
>>> s3='Hello'.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(s3)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> s1==s3
>>>True
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure if the way I'm doing it is right, my data is in the variable 'transposed', so according to your answer, I used unicode(transposed) and kept the rest same. Now my output csv file is split into individual letters.