# UnicodeWarning in Parse.py when integrating Parse Crash Reporting

Tags: python, ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to integrate Parse Crash Reporting into my app, following the [quick start guide provided](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/crashreporting/ios/existing).

I've added the following script to my `Build Phases > Run Script` section. I have added my Parse Cloud Code directory in my project directory, hence `$SRCROOT/parse`.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd $SRCROOT/parse

parse symbols "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

However, when I build the app, I got the following error message:

```
/usr/local/bin/parse/parse.py:825: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
Path doesn't match any symbol uploader.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've successfully added the Crash Reporting SDK to another app. I've no idea why it doesn't work in this.

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193305/python-unicode-equal-comparison-failed

Comment: @m170897017 Thanks. I found out the cause was due to non-english characters in my  target name.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the cause of the problem, it is because my target name is in non-English characters. Fixed it by renaming the target name in Xcode.