# UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I know many people encountered this error before but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

I have a URL that I want to normalize:

```
url = u"http://www.dgzfp.de/Dienste/Fachbeitr%C3%A4ge.aspx?EntryId=267&Page=5"
scheme, host_port, path, query, fragment = urlsplit(url)
path = urllib.unquote(path)
path = urllib.quote(path,safe="%/")
```

This gives an error message:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib.py:1236: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  res = map(safe_map.__getitem__, s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "url_normalization.py", line 246, in <module>
    logging.info(get_canonical_url(url))
  File "url_normalization.py", line 102, in get_canonical_url
    path = urllib.quote(path,safe="%/")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib.py", line 1236, in quote
    res = map(safe_map.__getitem__, s)
KeyError: u'\xc3'
```

I tried to remove the unicode indicator "u" from the URL string and I do not get the error message. But How can I get rid of the unicode automatically because I read it directly from a database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python unicode equal comparison failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193305/python-unicode-equal-comparison-failed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`urllib.quote()` does not properly parse Unicode. To get around this, you can call the `.encode()` method on the url when reading it (or on the variable you read from the database). So run `url = url.encode('utf-8')`. With this you get:

```
import urllib
import urlparse
from urlparse import urlsplit

url = u"http://www.dgzfp.de/Dienste/Fachbeitr%C3%A4ge.aspx?EntryId=267&Page=5"
url = url.encode('utf-8')
scheme, host_port, path, query, fragment = urlsplit(url)
path = urllib.unquote(path)
path = urllib.quote(path,safe="%/")
```

and then your output for the `path` variable will be:

```
>>> path
'/Dienste/Fachbeitr%C3%A4ge.aspx'
```

Does this work?

Comment: This works for me. Thank you. Actually, I printed type(url) before and after encoding and found that it is <type 'unicode'> before encoding and <type 'str'> after encoding.