# quote_plus URL-encode filter in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

There is a [`urlencode`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templates/#urlencode) filter in Jinja, which can be used with `{{ url | urlencode }}`, but I'm looking for a "plus" version that replaces spaces with `+` instead of `%20`, like `urllib.quote_plus()`. Is there anything off the shelf or is it a time for a custom filter?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, Jinja2 does not have a built-in method that functions like `quote_plus`; you will need to create a custom filter.

**Python**

```
from flask import Flask
# for python2 use 'from urllib import quote_plus' instead
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

app = Flask('my_app')    
app.jinja_env.filters['quote_plus'] = lambda u: quote_plus(u)
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
   {% set url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450404/quote-plus-urlencode-filter-in-jinja' %}
   {{ url|quote_plus }}
</html>
```

Comment: I do get an issue with this, and that is the following when applying for example |quote_plus to `XXX%20YYY`. I get an error as follows: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib.py:1303: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

Comment: @Navonod you are possibly using a mixture of `str` and `unicode`. Take a look at this question for more information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193305/python-unicode-equal-comparison-failed

Comment: I have converted now using .encode("utf-8"), which means the quote_plus now works, but now I'm getting a nasty b'string' in my results

Comment: @disruptive That makes... no sense at all. Your error clearly indicates you're in Python 2, but the `b'...'` representation of byte strings is only used for display in Python 3, to the best of my knowledge; Python 2.7 will understand `b'foo'` as a synonym of `'foo'` but will never choose to print a string with the `b` prefix. Unless you're using some `__future__` imports that change that, perhaps? An MCVE might make for an interesting `python2` question.

Comment: Why not use `env.filters['quote_plus'] = quote_plus`?

Answer (score 0):

## FastAPI variant

```
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
templates.env.filters['quote_plus'] = lambda x: quote_plus(str(x)) if x else ''
```

HTML code is same as in @wondercricket 's answer

```
<html>
    {% set url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450404/quote-plus-urlencode-filter-in-jinja' %}
    {{ url|quote_plus }}
</html>
```