# How to pass data from one view to another one in Fastapi?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a variable set in one view in Fastapi and want to pass it to another one :

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Response
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/my-first-view")
async def function1(request: Request) -> Response:
    """Display the home page."""
    my_variable = value
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "home.jinja",
        context={
           "my_variable": my_variable
        },
    )

@router.get("/my-second-view")
async def function2(request: Request, my_variable: str) -> Response:
    """Display the variable processing page."""
    
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "page.jinja"
    )
```

Normally, this would come to send `my_variable` from `home.jinja` to `page.jinja`.
Thus, in `home.jinja` I have the following :

```
...
<a href="{{url_for('function2', my_variable=my_variable)}}" title="connect">Connect</a>
...
```

But this is throwing me an error : `"starlette.routing.NoMatchFound: No route exists for name \"function2\" and params \"my_variable\".\n"`. I did some researches but I haven't found something really helpful

What is the proper way to do it with Fastapi ? What am I missing ?

Comment: use cookies/session so that each user carries their own variable. Otherwise you may show a variable from one user to another.

Comment: Starlette's `url_for` does not support query arguments directly. You can instead add them directly after the `url_for` part: `{{ url_for(...) }}?my_variable={{ my_variable }}` (and [apply a filter for query param escaping if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450404/quote-plus-url-encode-filter-in-jinja2)). Also see [Chris' answer about url_for in Starlette for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71067363/send-query-params-from-jinja-template).

Answer (score -1):

Very little context information on this post, so I'll help out with fixes that change as little as possible.

First of all, to fix your code you need a place to save the changes that you've made. A variable that only exists in a function is deleted at the end of that function.

Now usually you'd give more information regarding your use case, and I'd give you the best choice and why. It could be to store data in a JSON file, or a Database, or an in memory object that would serve the purpose best.

Here there's no info so we'll just make a variable. Keep in mind that this variable will be reset every time you restart the shell. So if your API is not "always on" then this may no work.

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Request, Response
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

VARIABLE = None
API_URL = "my_domain.com/api"

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/my-first-view")
async def function1(request: Request) -> Response:
    """Display the home page."""
    my_variable = value
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "home.jinja",
        context={
           "complete_url": f"{API_URL}/my-second-view?my_variable={VARIABLE}"
        },
    )

@router.get("/my-second-view")
async def function2(request: Request, my_variable: str) -> Response:
    """Display the variable processing page."""

    VARIABLE = my_variable
    
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "page.jinja"
    )
```

As far as the template goes, you haven't shared `url_for`, but I suppose it just creates the path. I'd just make `home.jinja` as follows.

```html
<a href="{{ complete_url }}" title="connect">Connect</a>
```

Also I've replaced the `url_for` call with a simple f-string.
Depending on what you pass in your `VARIABLE` you may need to encode it.

For an example of that, please look at the following thread: [How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python)

Comment: thank you for your response. Yes, I was trying to be a bit 'global' as a general use case here. I'll provide further details if needed? Regarding this line `complete_url: url_for('function2', my_variable=VARIABLE)` I'm having `complete_url` and `url_for` not defined

Comment: I'll add a definition for those, but you have to give me the API hostname

Comment: Okay, may I please know how it is relevant..? It is not an information I can really disclose yet.

Comment: Fine I'll just put a placeholder in the code, make sure you change it in the real thing

Comment: Using global variables is bad, especially if your handlers using the variable are used concurrently. This has race conditions. Don't do that!

Comment: @TheFool, I get it thank you. I'm the one that kept the question a bit global for general use case as I was saying. I'll add further details.

Comment: Even for a general use case, its broken. You can do that only if your code is runs in a single thread sequentially.

Comment: Just for the record, @scr solution is doing what I intended to do in the initial wrapped up post. Just know that's not good practice and it's appropriate only in a specific case
`You can do that only if your code is runs in a single thread sequentially.`
as mentioned above.

Comment: @aaronted can I get the green check ?