# Base.py: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode in

Tags: python, django, unicode

I was taking a look to a couple of related questions which treats about the same issue, but I still don't find a way to solve it.

It turns out that every time I execute a Django-related command, it prints me out the expected output plus something like this:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:307: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
return name == ":memory:" or "mode=memory" in force_text(name)
```

And here is the context of that line:

```
def is_in_memory_db(self, name):
    return name == ":memory:" or "mode=memory" in force_text(name)
```

Despite the Django server works, it's kind of annoying having always this message          printed out on my screen. So, why is this happening and how could this be solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python unicode equal comparison failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193305/python-unicode-equal-comparison-failed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [decode('utf-8')](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) to make correct comparing:

```
name.decode('utf-8') == ":memory:" or "mode=memory" in force_text(name)
```

Use full info:

[Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html)

[Solving Unicode Problems in Python 2.7](https://www.azavea.com/blog/2014/03/24/solving-unicode-problems-in-python-2-7/)

Comment: with decode() instead of encode() it worked. Thank you