# python: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a `dict` and want to search in it.

```
test = dict({u'K\xfcndigung' : 123})
tmpKey = str('K\xfcndigung')
print(test[tmpKey])
```

It results in:

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both 
arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

Comment: Is this Python2 or 3 ?

Comment: That code works in Python 3.5.2.

Comment: It's python 2.7

Comment: Should have been flagged as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193305/python-unicode-equal-comparison-failed

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Python2, :

```
>>> test[tmpKey]

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 1
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    test[tmpKey]
KeyError: 'K\xfcndigung'
```

Well in Python2, `str` are not unicode as opposed in Python3, thus make `tmpKey` as a unicode object instead:

```
>>> tmpKey = u'K\xfcndigung'
>>> #        ^
>>> 
>>> test[tmpKey]
123
```