# Python Unicode warning when using '

Tags: python-3.x, csv, unicode, utf-8, web-scraping

I am trying to run some code that will get data from a website(ques) and compare it to a CSV(ans) file to get a result.

```
def ans(ques):
    ans = False
    csvfile = open('database.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if ques == row[0]:
            ans = row[1]
            break
        if ques == row[1]:
            ans = row[0]
            break
    return(ans)
```

CSV file:

```
QUESTION,ANSWER
1+1=?,It's 2
```

When i run this code i get this:

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to 
Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

However when i remove the `'` it works as expected. Any help?

Comment: And what's the parameter `ques`?

Comment: ques is the data that is scraped from the web page. In this case, it is "It's 2" i am working back from the answer to find the question it belongs to.

Comment: See this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193305/python-unicode-equal-comparison-failed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python unicode equal comparison failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193305/python-unicode-equal-comparison-failed)

Comment: As far as I know, this warning doesn't exist in Python 3. It looks like you are using Python 2.x, and the linked post above applies.